# Variable in all controller and view fullcalendar laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, fullcalendar, laravel-5.6

I use fullcalendar in my web site in laravel 5.6 and it working :) but when i change view i have this problem :

`Undefined variable: calendar_details`

In my view layout.app i have this :

```
{!! $calendar_details->script() !!}
```

Can i define this var in all controller and view to avoid all problem ?

This is my EventsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Validator;
use App\Events;

use Calendar;

class EventsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $events = Events::get();
        $event_list = [];
        foreach ($events as $key => $event){
            $event_list[] = Calendar::event(
                $event->event_name,
                true,
                new \DateTime($event->start_date),
                new \DateTime($event->end_date)
            );
        }
        $calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list);

        return view('events', compact('calendar_details'));
    }

    public function addEvent(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'event_name' => 'required',
            'start_date' => 'required',
            'end_date' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()){
            \Session::flash('warning', 'Veuillez entrer des informations valide');
            return Redirect::to('/events')->withInput()->withErrors('warning');
        }

        $event = new Events;
        $event->event_name = $request['event_name'];
        $event->start_date = $request['start_date'];
        $event->end_date = $request['end_date'];
        $event->save();

        \Session::flash('success', 'Evènement ajouté avec succès');
        return Redirect::to('/events');

    }

}
```

and this is my Events.php :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Events extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'event_name', 'start_date', 'end_date'
    ];
}
```

Comment: You can use view composer to share this variable for all the places where you use this layout file https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

Comment: Thanks x) but im beginner in laravel can you say me more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open you **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider** and in the *boot()* method add this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Events;
use Calendar;
...
View::composer('layout', function ($view) {
    $events = Events::get();
    $event_list = [];
    foreach ($events as $key => $event){
        $event_list[] = Calendar::event(
            $event->event_name,
            true,
            new \DateTime($event->start_date),
            new \DateTime($event->end_date)
        );
    }

    $view->with('calendar_details', Calendar::addEvents($event_list));
});
```

Note that the class imports should be at the top of your file. What this code does is every time the *layout* view is compile, it would add the calendar_details.

Comment: I have add this code in my boot() function and return this problem :

Class 'App\Providers\View' not found

I add at the top :

`use View;`

And i have the same error.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`

Comment: Ok ^^ this is working but in my calendar he display events in double.

In my EventsController i take back this variable and delete this ?

Comment: @LightNox, yes, you no longer need the calendar code in your controllers.

Comment: Wow x) now i have a problem with this :

{!! $calendar_details->calendar() !!}

in my events.blade.php

I delete the index() function in my EventsController

This var display calendar with events it seems to me

Comment: You don't have solution for this problem ? :)

Comment: @LightNox I don't understand what you ask.